# What is MSSRPD?

Tags: windows, search-engine, hostname, bing

Recently, I found that some searches in Firefox are redirected to Bing. (Instead of my primary search engine Google.)

I am not sure, but it seems that it is not bound to search but rather a hostname resolving. Since entering a single word that might be a hostname redirects to Bing. But entering more words searches using my primary search engine.

`hey` -> uses Bing to search

`hey hey` -> uses Google to search

I found that the resulting search url contains MSSRPD:

`http://www.bing.com/search?q=hey&form=MSSRPD`

I am wondering what is the MSSRPD and how can I uninstall/disable it, so my primary search engine is used?

**EDIT:** I have no directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Search Enhancement Pack\Search Helper\` on my computer.

**EDIT2:** Same problem in Safari.

Comment: Are you searching via the address bar or the actual search box?

Comment: Address bar, therefore I think it has something with hostname lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the answer](http://support.mozilla.com/nl/forum/1/694752#threadId700262): In case you have the same problem, go to registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters` and empty the `mshome.net` value from the `ICSDomain` key, then disable and re-enable your network adapter.

**UPDATE:** After few days, it stopped working again. I've found that IPv6 DNS is also redirecting to Bing. I don't know, where Windows get the IPv6 DNS since my DHCP server is not providing that and I have not set up that. So, I've disabled IPv6 for now and it works.

Comment: I think this can also be done by changing DNS settings on IPv4 and IPv6 in each adapter to "Append these DNS suffixes" and then adding a DNS suffix other than mshome.net.

Answer (score 2):

http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/06/microsoft-slips-ie-firefox-add-on-into-toolbar-update.ars

Comment: This article is one year old. It starts appearing in last one/two weeks.

Comment: Yes, but I have deleted `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Search Enhancement Pack\Search Helper\`, restarted Firefox and it is still doing that. I thing there is one more component...

Comment: Have you uninstalled FireFox extension also? Has it got disappeared from Extensions in browser?

Comment: Yes, it is not in Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem. I think the problem started when I installed Daemon Tools Lite but I'm not sure.

I used the Sytem Restore thing and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Thx, for info, I have not installed Daemon Tools. It seems to some Windows update. However System Restore will not help me, since next time I will get this again. I need to find, where I can disable that.